# Find if an element exists in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find if an element exists in `Array` with a name.
Couldn't figure out, how to achieve the same

```
let string = [{"plugin":[""]}, {"test": "123"}]
console.log(string);
console.log(string instanceof Array); //true
console.log("plugin" in string); //false
```

Comment: You'll have to look through each object in the array and test to see if it has a property with the name you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plugin` is not defined directly in the array, it is defined inside the object in the array.

Use the [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if any element in the array contain the given property.

```
array.find(o => o.hasOwnProperty('plugin'))
```

Use `hasOwnProperty` to check if object is having property.

```js
let array = [{"plugin":[""]}, {"test": "123"}];
let res = array.find(o => o.hasOwnProperty('plugin'));

console.log(res);
```

As an option, you can also use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
array.filter(o => o.hasOwnProperty('plugin')).length > 0;
```

```js
let array = [{"plugin":[""]}, {"test": "123"}];
let containsPlugin = array.filter(o => o.hasOwnProperty('plugin')).length > 0;

console.log(containsPlugin);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#some()` and `Object.keys()` and return `true/false` if object with specific **key** exists in array.

```js
let string = [{"plugin":[""]}, {"test": "123"}];

var result = string.some(o => Object.keys(o).indexOf('plugin') != -1);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look at following example code as a general answer for finding an element in an array in Javasript:

```
var power = [
    "Superman",
    "Wonder Woman",
    "Batman"
];

for (var i = 0; i < power.length && power[i] !== "Wonder Woman"; i++) {
    // No internal logic is necessary.
}

var rank = i + 1;

// Outputs: "Wonder Woman's rank is 2"
console.log("Wonder Woman's rank is " + rank);
```

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
let array = [{"plugin":[""]}, {"test": "123"}];
array.find(o => o.plugin).length
```

Comment: What if _o.plugin_ exists, but it is undefined? Or false?

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".